# Java Multiplication Expression Generator

Tags: java

The goal of this assignment is to generate a multiplication problem in class Multiplier to display in GameTester so that the user may input an answer. If incorrect 3 times, it will display the correct answer and then prompt whether or not they would like to play again. My overall issue is after they solve or fail to solve the problem and I prompt the next question they are unable to answer. I am looking for a more efficient way to display another question so that it is more fluid and continuous in the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameTester{

    public static String question;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Multiplier m = new Multiplier();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    question = m.generateProblem();
    System.out.println(question);
    int userAnswer = s.nextInt();
    if(userAnswer == m.checkAnswer()){
        System.out.println("Correct!! Want to play again?");
        s.nextLine();
        String user = s.nextLine();
        playAgain(user);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is incorrect. Try again!");
        s.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i <=1; i++){
        System.out.println(question);
        if(i != 1 && s.nextInt() != m.checkAnswer()){
            System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is incorrect. Try again!");
        }
        else if(i == 1 && s.nextInt() != m.checkAnswer()){
            System.out.println("The correct answer was " + m.checkAnswer());
            System.out.println("Want to play again?");
            s.nextLine();
            String user = s.nextLine();
            playAgain(user);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Correct!! Want to play again?");
            s.nextLine();
            String user = s.nextLine();
            playAgain(user);
        }
        }
    }
}

  public static void playAgain(String userInput){
      if(userInput.equals("yes")){
          Multiplier m2 = new Multiplier();
          question = m2.generateProblem();
          System.out.println(question);
      }
      else{
          System.exit(0);
      }
  }
}

import java.util.Random;
public class Multiplier{

    public static int product;


  public Multiplier(){

  }

  public static String generateProblem(){
    Random r = new Random();
    int term1 = r.nextInt(11);
    int term2 = r.nextInt(11);
    product = term1 * term2;
    String s = "How much is " + term1 + " times " + term2 + "?";
    return s;
  }

  public static int checkAnswer(){
      return product;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all a simple matter of utilizing a boolean flag and **while** loops at specific locations. By doing this you can actually eliminate the **playAgain()** method but on the same token, we create other methods to streamline the flow and eliminate duplicate code.

Since you've brought up the subject of flow, it's always a good idea to keep your Class's **main()** method clean and by clean I mean by only placing relevant code or calls pertaining to to the true flow of your application instead of filling it with what I call **method clutter**. Allow the **main()** method to deal with Command Line Arguments and call another method to actually start your application, branching can then go from there. Try to only place method calls that outline the true **main** flow of your application. Even though your project is a simple console application it's still a good habit to get into if for anything, the sake of readability. Then again...this is just my opinion and really holds no merit to any of the valid answers provided towards your post.

You might want to streamline your code like this:

```
package gametester;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameTester {

    public static String question;
    public static int questionCount = 0;
    private static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playQuiz();
    }

    private static void playQuiz() {
        boolean playAgain = true;
        System.out.println("First Question:");
        while (playAgain) {
            question = Multiplier.generateProblem();
            System.out.println(question);
            int userAnswer = getAnswer();
            playAgain = processAnswer(userAnswer);
        }
    }

    private static int getAnswer() {
        int answer = 0;
        while (true) {
            answer = 0;
            // Trap any non-numerical answers from User 
            try {
                answer = s.nextInt();
                s.nextLine();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                // Needed to clear the scanner buffer otherwise
                // this catch clause will play over and over again
                // indefinately. 
                s.nextLine();
                // Display an Input fault to User.
                System.err.println("Incorrect Numerical Response Provided "
                        + "(Numbers only please)! Try Again.\n");
                // Get another answer from User.
                continue;   
            }
            break; // Good input, get outta this loop
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private static boolean processAnswer(int userAnswer) {
        boolean pAgain = false;
        if (userAnswer == Multiplier.checkAnswer()) {
            System.out.print("Correct!! ");
            pAgain = promptPlayAgain();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is incorrect. Try again!");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(question);
                System.out.println("  (Attempt #: " + (i+2) + ")");
                int ans = getAnswer();

                if (i != 1 && ans != Multiplier.checkAnswer()) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is incorrect. Try again!");
                } else if (i == 1 && ans != Multiplier.checkAnswer()) {
                    System.out.println("The correct answer was " + Multiplier.checkAnswer());
                    pAgain = promptPlayAgain();
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Correct!! ");
                    pAgain = promptPlayAgain();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return pAgain;
    }

    private static boolean promptPlayAgain() {
        boolean pAgain = false;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Want to play again (y or n)?");
            String user = s.nextLine();
            if (user.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'n') {
                pAgain = false;
                break;
            } else if (user.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y') {
                pAgain = true;
                System.out.println("\nNext Question :");
                break;
            } else {
                System.err.println("Incorrect Response ('y' or 'n' exprected)! Try Again.\n");
            }
        }
        return pAgain;
    }
}
```

And your Multiplier Class:

```
package gametester;

import static gametester.GameTester.questionCount;
import java.util.Random;

public class Multiplier{

    public static int product;

  public Multiplier(){ }

  public static String generateProblem(){
    questionCount++;
    Random r = new Random();
    int term1 = r.nextInt(11);
    int term2 = r.nextInt(11);
    product = term1 * term2;
    String s = String.valueOf(questionCount) + ") How much is " + term1 + " times " + term2 + "?";
    return s;
  }

  public static int checkAnswer(){
      return product;
  }
}
```

Now, put a configurable time limit on each question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the asking of the question into a method `askQuestion`. This would instantiate a `Multiplier`, output the question, and take the user's response. Your method `askQuestion` could either return the `Multiplier`, or check the answer and return a `boolean` indicating whether they got it right.

Your `main` method would then mainly contain the control loop necessary to run the program. One useful tool for repeatedly asking something is a *do-while* loop, which runs a block of code at least once, and then repeatedly until a condition is satisfied. For example:

```
boolean Correct = false;
int Attempts = 0;
do {
    Correct = askQuestion();
    Attempts++;
} while (!Correct && Attempts < 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `while` loop as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Multiplier m = new Multiplier();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    question = m.generateProblem();
    System.out.println(question);
    String user;
    int count = 0;
    int userAnswer;
    while (true) {
        userAnswer = s.nextInt();
        if (userAnswer == m.checkAnswer()) {
            System.out.println("Correct!! Want to play again?");
            s.nextLine();
            user = s.nextLine();
            playAgain(user);
            count = 0;
        } else {
            if(count == 2){
                System.out.println("The correct answer was " + m.checkAnswer());
                System.out.println("Want to play again?");
                s.nextLine();
                user = s.nextLine();
                playAgain(user);
                count = 0;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is incorrect. Try again!");
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```